# Using CSS page breaks, but within an absolutely positioned DIV

Tags: asp.net, html, css, asp.net-ajax, modalpopupextender

I am using the ASP.NET AJAX ModalPopupExtender on a page. The popup contains details of one or more customer orders that need to be printed out. Each order needs to be on a separate page.

I should be able to use the CSS `page-break-after` style, but this does not work in this scenario as the ModalPopupExtender causes the containing `div` to be set to `position: absolute`.

Can anyone suggest a workaround?

For completeness, an example HTML page that illustrates the issue is below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Printing Pagination</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        div
        {
            padding: 10px;
            margin: 10px;
        }
        div.outer
        {
            border: solid 5px green;
            position: absolute;
            top: 100px;
            left: 100px;
            width: 200px;
        }
        div.page
        {
            border: solid 5px red;
        }
    </style>
    <style type="text/css" media="print">
        div.outer
        {
            border: none;
        }
        div.page
        {
            page-break-after: always;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="outer">
        <div class="page">
            This should be on page 1 when printed
        </div>
        <div class="page">
            This should be on page 2 when printed
        </div>
        <div class="page">
            This should be on page 3 when printed
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you not just add this bit of code to your print style?

```
div.outer { position: relative; }
```

It's deceptively simple, but when printing, I would doubt the client / report viewer would want anything to do with positioning and would care most about the content yeah?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I am using the gridster plugin, and have a number of absolutely positioned div's. The solution I ended up with was using `margin-top` for the divs that would be cut off, thus moving them below the page break.

If you are trying to reposition multiple elements, and you are using Sass, you could try something like:

```
@for $i from 1 through 10 {
  &[data-SOME-ATTR="#{$i}"] {
    margin-top: #{SOME_OPERATIONS}px;
  }
}
```